# Unable to access local website when connected to VPN

Tags: vpn, iis, cisco-vpn-client

Running a local website on IIS at the following address: http://localhost/DEV-ADMIN/

Everything works fine but as soon as I connect to my work's VPN (required to access services/database required for the website) when working from the site will appear to endlessly load.

Observing the requests in fiddler I can see that IIS doesn't make any response.

IIS logs do not seem to have any logs from requests made whilst the VPN is active.

The `Allow local LAN access` option is checked in the VPN settings.

Additional Information

```
OS: Windows 10 (build 10420)
CISCO VPN CLient: 5.0.07.0440
IIS: 10
```

Comment: Can you ping localhost when connected to VPN?

Comment: Yes, resolves address as <machinename>.<company>.co.uk with an IPv6 localhost address.

Comment: @jkovba VPN Client and OS version at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Can you show us your route table to?  It might be sending all traffic to your VPN.  Here's how you can get it on Windows: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490991.aspx

Comment: The Cisco client is one of those that has configuration options to prohibit access to local network resources when connected to the VPN.  Not sure you can change this, if it has been locked down by the VPN administrator.

Comment: And if you ping -4?

Comment: @ShaunVermaak gets a response from 127.0.0.1

Comment: Currently back at work on the network, will update question with route table when back at home.

Comment: It's possible that when you use the client to connect the VPN it's adding a route to your table that sends all traffic down the VPN instead of allowing local routing (a security feature most likely).  If so, it's probably something of the form, say: 0.0.0.0/0 192.168.1.1